# KafkaConsumer and ScheduledExecutorService doesn't work

Tags: java, apache-kafka, scheduled-tasks, kafka-consumer-api

I'm trying to schedule a KafkaConsumer.poll() using a ScheduledExecutorService.

**poll()**:

subscribes to topic, initializes a scheduler to run first lambda with delay of 1 second after every execution completed.
There are two options to stop scheduled task:

1. Second lambda (Callable object) becomes true - until polled records stored into HashMap on every execution contains message with key I'm looking for.
2. scheduled reaches timeout of 1 minute.

```
public void poll(String topic, String key) {
    log.info("Polling...");
    consumer.subscribe(Collections.singleton(topic));
    Scheduler scheduler = new Scheduler(1000);
    scheduler.fixedDelaySchedule(
        () -> {
            ConsumerRecords<String, E> records = consumer.poll(Duration.ofMillis(4000));
            records.forEach(record -> cache.put(record.key(), record));
            log.info(cache.toString());
            consumer.commitSync();
        },
        () -> cache.containsKey(key));
}
```

**scheduler.fixedDelaySchedule()**:

```
private static final BiFunction<ScheduledExecutorService, Callable<Boolean>, Runnable> cancelFunction =
          (service, condition) -> {
            return new Runnable() {
              @Override
              @SneakyThrows
              public void run() {
                if (condition.call()) {
                  service.shutdown();
                }
              }
            };
          };

@SneakyThrows
public void fixedDelaySchedule(Runnable function, Callable<Boolean> stopCondition) {
    ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(0);
    Runnable canceller = cancelFunction.apply(scheduler, stopCondition);
    scheduler.scheduleWithFixedDelay(function, 0, interval, MILLISECONDS);
    scheduler.scheduleWithFixedDelay(canceller, 0, interval, MILLISECONDS);
    scheduler.awaitTermination(60, SECONDS);
}
```

As result I get zero messages polled from kafka within 1 minute:

```
22-04-2021 15:32:45.750 [pool-13-thread-1] INFO  c.n.k.c.impl.KafkaConsumerClient.lambda$poll$1 - Polling... 
22-04-2021 15:32:47.301 [pool-13-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.kafka.clients.Metadata.update - [Consumer instanceId=ESO_retry_test_instance_id_0423764828, clientId=consumer-ies-slc_7691520826-ESO_retry_test_instance_id_0423764828, groupId=ies-slc_7691520826] Cluster ID: nBDatdysQ2KAKeiwGNEinA 
22-04-2021 15:32:47.305 [pool-13-thread-1] INFO  o.a.k.c.c.i.AbstractCoordinator.onSuccess - [Consumer instanceId=ESO_retry_test_instance_id_0423764828, clientId=consumer-ies-slc_7691520826-ESO_retry_test_instance_id_0423764828, groupId=ies-slc_7691520826] Discovered group coordinator brook-c.nonprod.us-west-2.aws.proton.nordstrom.com:9094 (id: 2147483641 rack: null) 
22-04-2021 15:32:47.318 [pool-13-thread-1] INFO o.a.k.c.c.i.AbstractCoordinator.sendJoinGroupRequest - [Consumer instanceId=ESO_retry_test_instance_id_0423764828, clientId=consumer-ies-slc_7691520826-ESO_retry_test_instance_id_0423764828, groupId=ies-slc_7691520826] (Re-)joining group 22-04-2021 15:32:49.753 [pool-13-thread-1] INFO  c.n.k.c.impl.KafkaConsumerClient.lambda$poll$1 - {} 
22-04-2021 15:32:50.754 [pool-13-thread-1] INFO  c.n.k.c.impl.KafkaConsumerClient.lambda$poll$1 - Polling... 
22-04-2021 15:32:51.858 [pool-13-thread-1] INFO  o.a.k.c.c.i.ConsumerCoordinator.performAssignment - [Consumer instanceId=ESO_retry_test_instance_id_0423764828, clientId=consumer-ies-slc_7691520826-ESO_retry_test_instance_id_0423764828, groupId=ies-slc_7691520826] Finished assignment for group at generation 1: {ESO_retry_test_instance_id_0423764828-4482ea43-5f87-48a4-8ef4-1ad7483d5fee=Assignment(partitions=[merch_inv_retry_orch_avro_test-0, merch_inv_retry_orch_avro_test-1])} 
22-04-2021 15:32:52.030 [pool-13-thread-1] INFO  o.a.k.c.c.i.AbstractCoordinator.onSuccess - [Consumer instanceId=ESO_retry_test_instance_id_0423764828, clientId=consumer-ies-slc_7691520826-ESO_retry_test_instance_id_0423764828, groupId=ies-slc_7691520826] Successfully joined group with generation 1 
22-04-2021 15:32:52.047 [pool-13-thread-1] INFO  o.a.k.c.c.i.ConsumerCoordinator.invokePartitionsAssigned - [Consumer instanceId=ESO_retry_test_instance_id_0423764828, clientId=consumer-ies-slc_7691520826-ESO_retry_test_instance_id_0423764828, groupId=ies-slc_7691520826] Adding newly assigned partitions: merch_inv_retry_orch_avro_test-0, merch_inv_retry_orch_avro_test-1 
22-04-2021 15:32:52.233 [pool-13-thread-1] INFO  o.a.k.c.c.i.ConsumerCoordinator.handle - [Consumer instanceId=ESO_retry_test_instance_id_0423764828, clientId=consumer-ies-slc_7691520826-ESO_retry_test_instance_id_0423764828, groupId=ies-slc_7691520826] Found no committed offset for partition merch_inv_retry_orch_avro_test-0 
22-04-2021 15:32:52.233 [pool-13-thread-1] INFO  o.a.k.c.c.i.ConsumerCoordinator.handle - [Consumer instanceId=ESO_retry_test_instance_id_0423764828, clientId=consumer-ies-slc_7691520826-ESO_retry_test_instance_id_0423764828, groupId=ies-slc_7691520826] Found no committed offset for partition merch_inv_retry_orch_avro_test-1 
22-04-2021 15:32:53.934 [pool-13-thread-1] INFO  o.a.k.c.c.i.SubscriptionState.maybeSeekUnvalidated - [Consumer instanceId=ESO_retry_test_instance_id_0423764828, clientId=consumer-ies-slc_7691520826-ESO_retry_test_instance_id_0423764828, groupId=ies-slc_7691520826] Resetting offset for partition merch_inv_retry_orch_avro_test-1 to offset 818824. 22-04-2021 15:32:53.941 [pool-13-thread-1] INFO  o.a.k.c.c.i.SubscriptionState.maybeSeekUnvalidated - [Consumer instanceId=ESO_retry_test_instance_id_0423764828, clientId=consumer-ies-slc_7691520826-ESO_retry_test_instance_id_0423764828, groupId=ies-slc_7691520826] Resetting offset for partition merch_inv_retry_orch_avro_test-0 to offset 962365. 22-04-2021 15:32:54.754 [pool-13-thread-1] INFO  c.n.k.c.impl.KafkaConsumerClient.lambda$poll$1 - {} 
22-04-2021 15:32:55.929 [pool-13-thread-1] INFO  c.n.k.c.impl.KafkaConsumerClient.lambda$poll$1 - Polling... 
22-04-2021 15:32:59.929 [pool-13-thread-1] INFO  c.n.k.c.impl.KafkaConsumerClient.lambda$poll$1 - {} 
22-04-2021 15:33:01.106 [pool-13-thread-1] INFO  c.n.k.c.impl.KafkaConsumerClient.lambda$poll$1 - Polling... 
22-04-2021 15:33:05.107 [pool-13-thread-1] INFO  c.n.k.c.impl.KafkaConsumerClient.lambda$poll$1 - {} 
22-04-2021 15:33:06.280 [pool-13-thread-1] INFO  c.n.k.c.impl.KafkaConsumerClient.lambda$poll$1 - Polling... 
22-04-2021 15:33:10.281 [pool-13-thread-1] INFO  c.n.k.c.impl.KafkaConsumerClient.lambda$poll$1 - {} 
22-04-2021 15:33:11.457 [pool-13-thread-1] INFO  c.n.k.c.impl.KafkaConsumerClient.lambda$poll$1 - Polling... 
22-04-2021 15:33:15.457 [pool-13-thread-1] INFO  c.n.k.c.impl.KafkaConsumerClient.lambda$poll$1 - {} 
22-04-2021 15:33:16.632 [pool-13-thread-1] INFO  c.n.k.c.impl.KafkaConsumerClient.lambda$poll$1 - Polling... 
22-04-2021 15:33:20.633 [pool-13-thread-1] INFO  c.n.k.c.impl.KafkaConsumerClient.lambda$poll$1 - {} 
22-04-2021 15:33:21.834 [pool-13-thread-1] INFO  c.n.k.c.impl.KafkaConsumerClient.lambda$poll$1 - Polling... 
22-04-2021 15:33:25.834 [pool-13-thread-1] INFO  c.n.k.c.impl.KafkaConsumerClient.lambda$poll$1 - {} 
22-04-2021 15:33:27.007 [pool-13-thread-1] INFO  c.n.k.c.impl.KafkaConsumerClient.lambda$poll$1 - Polling... 
22-04-2021 15:33:31.007 [pool-13-thread-1] INFO  c.n.k.c.impl.KafkaConsumerClient.lambda$poll$1 - {} 
22-04-2021 15:33:32.185 [pool-13-thread-1] INFO  c.n.k.c.impl.KafkaConsumerClient.lambda$poll$1 - Polling... 
22-04-2021 15:33:36.186 [pool-13-thread-1] INFO  c.n.k.c.impl.KafkaConsumerClient.lambda$poll$1 - {} 
22-04-2021 15:33:37.390 [pool-13-thread-1] INFO  c.n.k.c.impl.KafkaConsumerClient.lambda$poll$1 - Polling... 
22-04-2021 15:33:41.391 [pool-13-thread-1] INFO  c.n.k.c.impl.KafkaConsumerClient.lambda$poll$1 - {} 
22-04-2021 15:33:42.565 [pool-13-thread-1] INFO  c.n.k.c.impl.KafkaConsumerClient.lambda$poll$1 - Polling...
```

Then I get exception handled by me:

```
java.util.NoSuchElementException: Topic message with key [c17b6b3c-d84b-47a2-857d-ba836be96732-[0]-INVENTORY_ADJUSTMENT] wasn't found
```

Comment: You're seeking to the end of the topic, where there's probably no data produced within that minute - `Resetting offset for partition merch_inv_retry_orch_avro_test-0 to offset 962365`

Comment: What should I do to fix this?

Comment: In any case, you should pause the consumer in between polls or increase the heartbeat timeout. Otherwise, the consumer group rebalances

Comment: You can set `auto.offset.reset` not to be `latest` if you want to be earlier in the topic or you can manually track and seek to specific offsets

Comment: Also worth pointing out that this consumer pattern of caching keys is already solved with Kafka Streams KTables, and you could let that run in the background as a continuous thread rather than a timed loop

Comment: Thanks for the answers! auto.offset.reset doesn't solve the problem. Can't find someting related to my case of Kafka Streams usage. Didn't you have something useful?

Comment: You'd need to change or reset the group id for that property to take effect. I don't know your exact use case, but converting a topic to a table is straightforward enough. You could then periodically check if the key exists in the table. Also don't think you need to store the whole ConsumerRecord

Comment: unique group.id is generated every single run. I do need to get a ConsumerRecord by key to get its message and read its fields.

Comment: @OneCricketeer I would be very thankful if you will provide at least raw piece of code to convert my pooling to Kafka Streams with storing into KTables. I'm very new to it, can't get something useful on web ;(

Comment: Examples are mostly all here. Build a Stream, groupByKey, then reduce() or aggregate() is necessary to handle possible duplicate keys, and then you get a KTable object. After that, read the Interactive Queries page to see how you can query for a key https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/streams/developer-guide/dsl-api.html#aggregating

Comment: Thanks, will look at this topic.